# S3 Replication alternative

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kms

I'm looking for a way to replicate the contents of sourcebucket1/prefix1 to destinationbucket2-cross-account/prefix2 or even destinationbucket3-cross-account-cross-region/prefix3/prefix4 as they populate (for logs for example). Unfortunately, with s3 replication, there's no way to specify a prefix path on the destination bucket.

I still want all the native capabilities of s3 replication, such as encrypting the items in the destination bucket with a kms key in the destination account.

Is this capable with one lambda function in the source account? I believe copying to a prefixed path in a destination account will be possible, my concern is encrypting the destination items with a kms key in the destination account.

ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Comment: Please be aware this site can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question")

Comment: Yes, I think you'd just specify the KMS key in the copy request. Easiest way is to add a Bucket Policy to the destination bucket that grants access to the IAM Role used by the Lambda function in the source account. It would be harder to mimic versioning behaviour, but if you don't want that it should be quite simple. Easier still if the files are small enough not to require multi-part copy.